# Equation for harmonic oscillator with non linear damping

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What is a function for a forced harmonic oscillator with damping such that when the displacement in the graph is greater than zero it (damping coefficient) has on a certain value and when it is less than zero it has a different value.

I am not very good at math and my research didnt lead to any useful answers. I would really appreciate if i am pointed in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE community! To get better feedback or complete answer, please mention what are your observations and on which direction you have approached the problem. Could you please show us what are your primary observations!

Comment: So something like $$\ddot x+c(x)\dot x+\omega^2x=0~~?$$ And you are asking how to write a piecewise defined function $c(x)$?

Comment: I was actually looking for how to apply the concept of heaviside type function but a piecewise function is what i should be looking at right?